# Understanding ある

Tags: grammar

This may be an easy question for the all of you.

I saw somewhere a form of ある which was written as あるな and had the same meaning. I've only heard the form あります and that's it.

What does あるな then mean?

Comment: Can you provide the full sentence that you saw?

Comment: The full sentence is ここ家がいっぱいあるな！

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, あるな is simply ある (plain form of あります) with the [sentence ending particle な](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/advanced-sentence-ending-particles/#1), which wouldn't noticeably change the meaning in most cases. あるな isn't any type of form (to my knowledge).